# Color Parent Dropdown Cell Without Clearing Contents

Tags: excel, vba

Have had some great help from this forum on editing my codes. I need to update it just slightly, but can't seem to figure out the right solution. Essentially, my code allows for cell clearing and color in adjacent data validation dropdowns. I have the primary dropdown in column F, secondary dropdown in column G, and final dropdown in column H. My code works as such: if the primary dropdown value in column F changes, clear and color adjacent cells in column G and H. If only secondary dropdown value in column G changes, clear and color adjacent cells in column H.

What I need is if there is a change in primary dropdown in column F, not to clear contents, but only color the cell, while still clearing and coloring adjacent cells in column G and H, or clearing and coloring adjacent cells in column H if change in secondary dropdown in column G.

I tried adjusting the (For i = Target.Column + 1 To 8) to (For i = Target.Column + 0 to 8) and it does work with coloring the primary dropdown, but then it clears it. And I can't make a selection because it is clearing it consistently. Thus, I cannot make any adjacent dropdown selections.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    If Target.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub  'screen out multi-cell changes
    
    If Target.Column > 7 Then Exit Sub 'col 1/2
    
    If Not CellHasValidation(Target) Then Exit Sub '...with validation
    
    On Error GoTo haveError 'ensure events are not left off
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'loop to max column to be cleared
    For i = Target.Column + 1 To 8
        With Target.EntireRow.Cells(i)
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 44
            .Value = ""
        End With
    Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  
haveError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub

'check if a cell has validation
Function CellHasValidation(cell As Range) As Boolean
    Dim vt
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore if error (no validation)
    vt = cell.Validation.Type
    On Error GoTo 0 'stop ignoring errors
    CellHasValidation = Not IsEmpty(vt)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of troubleshooting, I was able to embed if statements into the code in order to test for the target column before running the entire row change.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    If Target.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub  'screen out multi-cell changes
    
    If Target.Column > 7 Then Exit Sub 'col 1/2
    
    If Not CellHasValidation(Target) Then Exit Sub '...with validation
    
    On Error GoTo haveError 'ensure events are not left off
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'loop to max column to be cleared
    If Target.Column = 6 Then
        ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    End If
    
    If Target.Column = 7 Then
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    End If
    
    For i = Target.Column + 1 To 8
        With Target.EntireRow.Cells(i)
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 44
            .Value = ""
        End With
    Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
    
haveError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub


'check if a cell has validation
Function CellHasValidation(cell As Range) As Boolean
    Dim vt
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore if error (no validation)
    vt = cell.Validation.Type
    On Error GoTo 0 'stop ignoring errors
    CellHasValidation = Not IsEmpty(vt)
End Function
```